# Selenium- Asserting search results total with the actual results in the body

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I'm having troubling figuring out how to assert the total number of search results with the actual results in the body of the page.

On the webpage I have: Showing: max of 100 out of 52042655

I want to make sure that 100 results are actually there on the page which inspecting under firepath I found is:

.//*[@id='resultsComponent']//*[@class='highlight-session

Can someone help find what the assert code would look like? Java/Selenium

Comment: Try to write a common xpath to match those 100 results displayed in the page

Comment: @ChetanPatel Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB This is the line before: 
 
   wt.waitForElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchServicePopup']/div[2]"), 5);
  main.clickServiceLogSearchBtn();
   test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Clicked on Service Search");

Now I want to verify that 100 of the UI elements are actually displaying on the page. When I got the session ID xpath, I made sure there was 100 nodes, so its correct.

Comment: @santhoshkumar I did that, and I found the 100 nodes... but how would the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the xpath which matches all the 100 nodes in the page. Then store all the Webelements in a list and get the size of the list. Use condition statements for assertion. Below code can give you an idea,

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.xpath("XPATH HERE"));   
//Get the Total Count
System.out.println(results.size());
if(results.size() ==100)
{
    System.out.println("100 REsults are found as Expected");
}

//To display the http value for each results
for(WebElement each : results)
{
    System.out.println(each.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it works! One more question, if the result is less than 100, will the code be the same? @santhoshkumar

Comment: Yes. It will be same.. but you won't get 100 results are found getting printed